# Hibernate fails to locate named parameter with querydsl

Tags: hibernate, querydsl

After upgrading from hibernate 5.0.11.Final to 5.3.10.Final with querydsl 4.0.9

I'm getting this error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate named parameter [1], expecting one of []
```

- Already tried upgrading querydsl to 4.2.1
- Already tried adding @Param to my method signature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a compatibility issue with Hibernate 5.3.

You can find a ticket about this issue there:
https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/2326

> QueryDSL relied on Hibernate's behaviour that a positional parameter
>   was basically a named parameter. This is no longer the case since
>   5.3.0.Beta1 (see the Hibernate ticket that @jpimag mentioned above).
>
> From now on, QueryDSL needs to keep its positional parameters
>   separated from the named parameters.

There is no official fix at this moment (QueryDSL version 4.2.1 - Mar 22, 2018)